# What is the purpose and risks of enabling SQL CLR?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, tsqlt

We are looking to implement unit tests using the tSQLt test framework. It has got a pre-requisite that the SQL CLR must be enabled using this command:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1; RECONFIGURE;
```

I am curious to know what is the purpose of SQL CLR and the risks of enabling this in production environment?

Comment: SQLCLR is needed when T-SQL alone isn't sufficient for required functionality. In the case if tSQLt, it uses CLR objects to provide unit testing functionality that cannot be accomplished with the T-SQL language. Enabling CLR does add to the surface area so it should only be enabled when you need it. Not sure why you would run unit tests in production, though. It would be better to leave it disabled in prod and run unit tests in a test environment.

Comment: I completely agree with @DanGuzman re: not doing unit testing in Production. That just seems like a problem waiting to happen, regardless of SQLCLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PURPOSE**

SQLCLR allows one to do things that either:

1. can't be done in T-SQL, or
2. can't be done as efficiently as in T-SQL

There are plenty of things that can be done in both, and for which T-SQL is actually much better at. In those cases it is an inappropriate use of SQLCLR to do those things so it is best to research first to make sure that the operation cannot be done in T-SQL, or would definitely be slower.

For example of performance, T-SQL Scalar UDFs prevent parallel execution plans. But SQLCLR scalar UDFs, as long as there is no data access and that they are marked as `IsDeterministic=true`, do *not* prevent parallel execution plans.

For more details on what SQLCLR is and is not, please see the first article in the [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) series that I am writing for SQL Server Central:

[Stairway to SQLCLR Level 1: What is SQLCLR?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/104406/)

Or, to get a sense of what can be done in SQLCLR, please see my SQL# project, which is a library of over 320 stored procedures and functions, many of which are in the Free version, and many of which work in `SAFE` mode: [SQLsharp.com](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_50761586).

**RISKS**

The risks vary based on the `PERMISSION_SET` (i.e. `SAFE`, `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, and `UNSAFE`) that the Assembly is marked as, and what is being done. It is possible to do things in an UNSAFE Assembly that cannot be done in regular T-SQL (except that many of those dangerous things can already be done via some extended stored procedures, xp_cmdshell, and the OLE Automatic procedures -- `sp_OA*` ). An Assembly marked as `SAFE` cannot reach outside of the database, so generally quite safe, BUT you can still lock up the system via a Regular Expression that exposes "catastrophic backtracking" (of course, this can be mitigated starting in .NET Framework 4.5, so SQL Server 2012 and newer, by setting a max time limit on the RegEx operation). An Assembly marked as `UNSAFE` can write to static variables, which in the context of the shared App Domain model used by SQLCLR, allows for shared memory between Sessions. This can allow for caching, but when not used properly, easily leads to race conditions.

**TESTING**

As for tSQLt, I do not believe that you are required to use the SQLCLR component. I thought I saw that it just enabled some extended functionality. Either way, the source code is available on GitHub so you can check it out to see what it is doing. It has been a while since I looked at it, but from what I remember, it should not present much of a risk for the little that it is doing (especially in a Dev / QA environment).

Another option that doesn't use SQLCLR is DbFit. I have always prefered DbFit as it is completely external to the DB. It is based on the FitNesse framework, written in Java, and you manage the tests via wiki-style pages. It, by default, wraps the tests in a Transaction and rolls everything back when the test is finished (i.e. clean-up). It is worth taking a look at.

Download: [DbFit project on GitHub](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/)
Tutorial: [Using the DbFit Framework for Data Warehouse Regression Testing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/using-dbfit-framework-data-warehouse-regression-testing/)

Comment: How do I check the permission set value?

Comment: Also, can we consider DbFit good to be used on production database?

Comment: **1)** You can check the `PERMISSION_SET` values using the following query: `SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies;`. **2)** DbFit is "better" (in my opinion) because it does not add anything to the server or database that it is testing. HOWEVER, you should _never_ do testing in Production, no matter what method you choose.

Answer (score 1):

SQLCLR allows you to create .NET assemblies and run code inside them from within SQL Server.

Depending on the permissions on the assembly the risks vary. The risks are something like so:

Permission Set:    Risk
`SAFE`             You cannot do anything more than what you can in T-SQL. So fairly safe.

`EXTERNAL ACCESS`   You can call code in .NET assemblies approved by Microsoft, such as ADO.NET. Fairly safe, but still a risk.

`UNSAFE`            You can do almost anything that the .NET framework allows you to do. In reality, shoot yourself in the head unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: How do I check the permission set value?

Comment: As @Solomon Rutzky commented above, you can check the permission value by:
`SELECT permission_set_desc FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'some_assembly_name'`.